# the average latency is 500 ms when I ping my PC in a LAN

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10, ping

In my network I have a 
Raspberry pi connectet via wifi 
And a pc optiplex 5050 running a fresh install of the Ubuntu 17.10 connected with the network adapter D-LINK DWA-548/EU.
When I ping from the raspberry to the pc the average latency is 500 ms. In the other side the average la tency when I ping from the pc to the raspberry is less than 10 ms.
I have tested the download speed (speedtest-cli) in both of them and the results are the same.
I don’t know if I have a hardware or driver problem in PC

more detail about the wireless pci card with 
lshw -class network
lspci
rfkill list all

```
root@zed-home:/home/tza# lshw -class network
  *-network
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: RT5392 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       fabriquant: Ralink corp.
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nom logique: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       numéro de série: 40:9b:cd:02:ed:48
       bits: 32 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.13.0-38-generic firmware=0.40 ip=192.168.1.52 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       ressources: irq:16 mémoire:f7100000-f710ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: Ethernet Connection (5) I219-V
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 1f.6
       information bus: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       nom logique: enp0s31f6
       version: 00
       numéro de série: 50:9a:4c:31:e0:99
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 32 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       ressources: irq:124 mémoire:f7200000-f721ffff
root@zed-home:/home/tza# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 591f (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH LPC Controller (Q270)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PMC
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (5) I219-V
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5392 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
root@zed-home:/home/tza# rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
root@zed-home:/home/tza#
```

Comment: Have you tried it with another OS so we can be sure this is due to Ubuntu and not the network?

Comment: I don’t want to by a windows license just to test the network :)

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer. https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

the solution was to edit default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

and change wifi.powersave = 3 to wifi.powersave = 0
Source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333291